# Search in all files does not show preview

Tags: webstorm

When I used to search in all files, I could see the preview of the selected file, for example:

[image]

but now it just shows the file list:

[image]

What happened, any idea?

Comment: You should probably use https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/resolve-conflicts.html anyway

Comment: For reference purposes: the same of WebStorm Forums -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5369714374162-Search-in-all-files-does-not-show-preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have manually hide the preview area somehow. You now need to show it back by changing its size.

1. Move your mouse cursor over the bottom of the window, just above the area where `registered.js` and black rectangular area is displayed.
2. Mouse pointer should change the shape. When it does that, click and drag it up.

[image]